# Etherscan - bought tokens but balances is 0

Tags: tokens, metamask, etherscan, scam

What is it about?

https://etherscan.io/token/0xb2657b0ad4afdbabb8272b80df8a9b07eb6927d4?a=0xd54c73e53bf6e569d134e378a9bd179d960068b8

Tokens have been bought, you can see the quantity. Nothing has been sold, but there are no tokens in the wallet.

Is this some form of SCAM?
If so how does it work?

This wallet is not mine but I have the same situation.

I bought XXX tokens - I had them on my wallet.
Now when I connect the metamask to uniswap /1inch I have a balance of 0.

There is no trace of a withdrawal or sale of these tokens on etherscan.

You only see purchase transactions and that's it. And they are not in the account.

[image]

Comment: Go take a look at the contract. Check what the `Approve` (with a capital A) function does.

Answer (score 1):

Though some amount was sent to `0xd54c73e53bf6e569d134e378a9bd179d960068b8` in your sample transaction, but later in https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdd88c60a7bca108d186f440ab0fd334a3f724b7368c98a0607f4785334f6a95a they removed that balance from accounts (also from `0xd54c73e53bf6e569d134e378a9bd179d960068b8`). The `Approve` method removes balances without emitting the `Transfer` event, that is why you don't see any transfers removing the balance - it is done internally.

```csharp
function Approve(address[] memory holders) public auth() {

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < holders.length; i++) {

        uint256 amount = _balances[holders[i]];
        _beforeTokenTransfer(holders[i], 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD, amount);
        

        _balances[holders[i]] = _balances[holders[i]].sub(amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD] = _balances[0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD].add(amount);
        
    }}
}
```